# DefaultExtension not working in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying to setup a basic Angular 2 app with TypeScript. But I'm stuck because `SystemJS` doesn't seem to be doing anything with the `defaultExtension: 'js'` option.

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/test/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

  <script>
    System.config({ packages: { app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js', } } });
    System.import('backend/app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app>Loading</app>
</body>
</html>
```

But this then gives me the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:1122/test/backend/app/boot 404 (Not Found)
```

I **can** add the `.js` extension to the path in the `System.import` command, so that it looks like this:

```
System.import('backend/app/boot.js')
```

Then it **is** able to find `boot.js`, but then it complains that it **can't** find `app.component`. So basically I have to add a `.js` extension to that import as well and for every other component that I will have in my application.

I don't think that's the solution I have to go for. So how can I fix this `System.import` problem? It looks like that it is ignoring `defaultExtension: 'js'` for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting the `js` as the default extension for the `app` package, but your code is in `backend/app`, not `app`, either remove the backend folder or fix your package config.

Answer (score 2):

Just trying out Angular2 and had the same problem. I guess, another option could be using baseURL. E.g.:

```
System.config({
        baseURL: 'backend/',
        packages: { 
                app: { 
                    format: 'register', 
                    defaultExtension: 'js', 
                } 
        } 
});

System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I could find the following solution.
Use map to add your extra path to your app folder like this

```
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: { 'app': './backend/app' }
    });
    System.import('app/boot');
```